# Accessing an object of another class without delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I created an object in a ViewController A based on the MVC model:

```
carArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Car *aCar = [[Car alloc] init];
aCar.title = @"bla";
aCar.coordinate = CLLocationCordiante2DMake(123,123);
[carArray addObject: aCar];
[aCar release];
```

Now I want to access my aCar object from another view controller B. I have tried to synthesize the View controller A that includes my car object. But I always get the message:

> Request for member aCar in something not a structure or union.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the header file for ViewControllerA in the ViewControllberB file so that it knows that ViewControllerA has that property.